# Issues Getting Started with Restcomm

Tags: voip, ussd, mobicents, restcomm

I've been trying to get started with programming with Restcomm for a few weeks now, and I'm having trouble figuring what I need in order to get myself set up with all of the services.

So far, I have gotten myself situated with the Restcomm software via the AWS Marketplace; I am able to log into the software, but have failed to register a phone number yet.  Whenever I select a number from the page by clicking "Register Number," a message comes up saying that registration "failed" without any additional information.

Additionally, I have downloaded and unzipped the folders for Mobicents (which I have not read much about the use of on my desktop yet) and the Telscale USSD Gateway (which I have read most of the background documentation for, but am yet to get in motion with because of my inability to utilize Restcomm).

I have really been trying to make sense of all of these pieces on my own, but I'm at a point of frustration.  Could I get some guidance just walking me through what I need in order to get started with using Restcomm and having functions through telephones correspond with a simple database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you have been able to log into Restcomm AMI, you should be able to use the pre-packaged demo apps. Here is the documentation explaining how to test the demo apps. http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-testing-default-demos/

Comment: Hi @TechKid Which Demo I can see to do push IVR, Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jrey, If you want to see how to build a simple IVR with Restcomm, use this tutorial http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-create-an-ivr-app-with-rvd/